# Post file (picture) with JSON in Express and Axios

Tags: node.js, json, express, axios

I want one single route for posting a picture file along with some JSON data.

It all works except that i get a string on the express back-end, which i can't convert to a javascript object, so i can't use it to store the information in the database (mongo).

With the send the header is set to    `'Content-Type': multipart/form-data;`, the picture is stored with multer. but I get a string with the JSON information: `{ code: 'ducns', type: '%', value: '3' }`. I Don't know how to convert this back in a javascript object.

Without picture and with `Content-Type': 'application/json` it works als fine.

but the combination gives troubles..

In the frond end it works als follows

```
data = new FormData();
  data.append('picture', {
    uri: picture,
    name: 'test.jpg',
    type: 'image/jpg',
  });
  data.append(
    'data',
    JSON.stringify({
      code: code,
      type: type,
      value: value,
    })
  );

  const res = await api.post('/', picture, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${data._boundary}`,
    },
  });
```

Back-end:

```
router.post('/', upload.single('couponpicture'), // works as it should
    async (req, res) => {console.log(req.body.data);}
```

Which gives the response as a string.

Comment: Does `JSON.parse` not give you the json object?

Comment: Ok, this is really wierd!! I had tried that before, but it gave an error after JSON. (expecting a ', ') This morning I try it again to show the results, and it works?!? Wel  thanks, anyway! (i've worked about 10hr straight on this problem...)